# Html css готовые компоненты

Tags: html, css

Должен реализовать сайт небольшой, ищу библиотеку кнопок и всех других компонентов реализованных на css и html. Типо зашел выбрал компонент с дизайном и взял его исходный код. Неужели таких сайтов нет для веб компонентов?

Comment: Например bootstrap, http://getbootstrap.ru/docs/v4-alpha/components/buttons/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Среди наиболее популярных - это bootstrap и foundation. На официальных сайтах прям целиком блоки можно копировать и вставлять себе на сайт (подключив предварительно соответствующий css-файл)